# My Angular 5 App is not loading in mobile Devices with Android 4.4.4 and 5.0.1

Tags: android, angular, firebase, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Hotjar to record the users actions and I have seen that the session time of some users is less than 5 seconds and for me this is bad, when I checked the recording of the users movements and I saw that my Angular 5 web app is not loading correctly in those users that have Android 5.0.1 and 4.4.4, with the others different Android versions there is not problem, It happens to 1 of every 20 or 30 users.

I have no idea how to solve this or debug the console in those specifics Android Versions.

- I'm using Angular 5.2.10 with a PWA Configuration in an Firebase
  Hosting
- Angular CLI 1.7.4
- Angular Material 5.2.5
- and angularfire2
       5.0.0-rc.7.0-next

the url for my web is [Pokemoneros.com](https://Pokemoneros.com) if you want to check how the page loads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `@angular/service-worker` package for service worker support. It has a bug that affects older versions of Chrome and some browsers that are built on top of it, like e. g. Samsung Internet Browser.
With those browsers, the second time the page is loaded "website unavailable" is shown, because the service worker script fails with `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished.`

Read more about this in the corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20756#issuecomment-361940313).

You can reproduce it by downloading the [Samsung Internet Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=de), loading and then reloading your page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew it, this is a big problem and is still an open issue since december 2017 :/ I hope Angular 6 fixes this, Now i Know why my site doesn't load on my Samsung TV. thanks for your answer.